# Confusion about the flow of current in a motional emf system

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

Down below is a conductive bar of length $L$ moving on two conductive rails in a magnetic field. I have a couple of questions regarding the flow of current in such a system.

How does the current flow through the closed circuit if the length of the bar $L$ is larger than the width of the rails $l$ ? I'm curious to know what is happening at the ends of the bar in particular. Do the electrons reach them and make a U-turn or something?

[image]

Comment: The energy doesn't flow in the electrons. It flows in the electromagnetic field surrounding the conductors (and a little bit of it flows on their inside because of skin effect). Energy flow is one of the limits of the classical electron-flow model in electrical conductors. It gives us the wrong intuition about what is happening. If you want to get the correct understanding, then you have to learn about Maxwell's equations and the Poynting vector.

Comment: @Flatterman you're just spreading the misconception popularized by youtubers that the energy flux vanishes in a perfect carrying current conductor. If you,want to learn.the truth, have a look at non eq. thermodynamics. There is definiteluy an energy flux due to moving charges.

Comment: @untreated_paramediensis_karnik Please note my remark "and a little bit of it flows on their inside because of skin effect". You are welcome to analyze energy flow in a transformer, or, if that is not enough... explain the energy flow of 1kW/m^2 on Earth's surface that is caused by solar radiation. There are certainly no wires involved there.

Comment: All emf's are "induced."  The normal term for the kind of emf you are talking about (due to the Lorentz force of a constant magnetic field on a moving circuit element) is "motional emf."

Comment: @Flatterman I know energy flows outside wires, and in space without any material. However it also flows with particle flow. One way to see this is by taking.the divergence of Ju, the internal energy flux. If you only consider EM energy with Poynting vector, you'll get an incorrect energy balance.and hear equatiob in the wire. If you consider the full enerfy balance, you'll get the correct heat eq. So I stand my pojnt, claiming that energy doesnt flow inside wires is false.

Comment: @untreated_paramediensis_karnik Please reread my comment. I clearly mentioned both components. For problems like these, however, the motion of electrons can be completely neglected. What the electrons do, in this case, is mostly to form the boundary conditions of the fields that make them "stick" to the wires. They do, of course, cause the energy loss in the conductors and the resistor. That's a detrimental property of classical conduction.

Comment: @FlatterMann I have just reread your first comment, and I still disagree (slightly). The electrons do carry an energy with them. In a wire with DC (no skin effect), there is an energy flux that goes along with the electrons (in their direction, and inside the wire). Do you agree with this statement? Edit: I am not talking about an energy loss due to Joule effect which of course occurs (that would be a heat generation, not a heat flux). I am talking about an energy flux.

Comment: @untreated_paramediensis_karnik Electrons moving at a few um per second (the drift speed in a typical metal) carry very little kinetic energy.

Comment: @FlatterMann I think you are correct, and I stand corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All along the moving rod, including the ends beyond the rails, its charges experience the magnetic Lorentz force, $\vec F=q\vec v \times \vec B$. The free electrons are urged towards the end of the rod furthest from us (the viewer).

Some free electrons in the end nearest us will move out of the end into the main circuit, leaving the end positively charged as long as the rod's motion continues. Likewise some free electrons will move out of the main circuit into the end furthest from us making it negatively charged.

These 'chargings of the ends' will happen very quickly. [The unbalancing of charges will give rise to electric fields and electric Lorentz force ($\vec F=q\vec E$) on the free electrons in the ends of the rods that will quickly counterbalance the magnetic Lorentz forces on them so no more charge will accumulate.]

As the rod continues to move, free electrons from the middle section of the rod will escape from the rod itself to process around the circuit mabnm..., their drift speed being limited by the resistance due to their collisions with ions in the metal.

Answer (score 5):

The current will take the path of least resistance and so will flow from the bar to the rails. The ends of the bar can essentially be ignored regarding the electron flow.